# Is it possible to make only the console background dark in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, background, color-scheme

I know it's possible to set a dark background for all editor windows, including the console (*Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Console Colors → Scheme*), but I like the light mode. Just the console needs to be dark for my LS color theme to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Having the Light theme set go to

> Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Color -> Console -> Background

Set the background color to whatever color you want, e.g. `000000`.

[image]

Also change *Error output*, *Standard output*, *System output* and *User input* to colors of your choice so that those won't be identical to the background color set.